# How to query in one to many relation with where condition in parent and child fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Parent Table - Migration File

```
Schema::create('schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('location_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreignId('service_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('start_date');
    $table->timestamp('end_date')->nullable();
    $table->foreignId('created_by_user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Child Tabe - Migration File

```
Schema::create('schedule_day_times', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('schedule_id');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('day_name')->nullable();
    $table->time('start_time');
    $table->time('end_time')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The relationship in parent schedule.php

```
public function dayTimes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ScheduleDayTime');
}
```

What is the best way to two write a query for the below condition?

```
//$appointment_at = Carbon::tomorrow()->addHours(8);
Query where appointment_at is between start_date and end_date and start_time and end_time.
```

Comment: Is there anything you've tried so far?

Comment: @Rwd Hi. The soulution given by Uzair worked for me. However, I am trying to make DigitalDrifter solution work. Once I implement any of these two solutions I will TICK that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do `->whereHas` on `dayTimes` like so:

```
Schedule::whereHas('dayTimes', function (Builder $query) use ($appointment_at) {
            $query->where('start_time', '<=', $appointment_at)
                ->where('end_time', '>=', $appointment_at);
        })
            ->whereDate('start_date', '<=', $appointment_at->timestamp)
            ->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $appointment_at->timestamp)
            ->get();
```